# When using mongoose, how can I imply required validation only to the field inside the object where the object itself can be null?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

here is my simple schema for my model

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    User: {{
        Name:{ type: String, required: true }
    }
    },
    Amount: { type: Number, required: true }
})

var model = cnn.model("test", schema);
var first = new model({Amount:12});
```

What I am expecting is that the'required option only apply if I create an object with User. When I create a object without User, I don't need to check.
That is if the path is without User, it should have also User.Name, if it doesn't, it's also ok

But the way I set up the schema seems failed when I try to store the object without User and it says that: Path `User.Name` is required.

So is there anyway in monoose library that can realize my intention?